# Element type 'date' when accessed by getElementsByTagName() shows it as 'text'

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

When I try to access the type of the first textbox, it shows "text" instead of "date" whereas when I try to access the size of the text, it shows the correct value.

Why is it so? How can I check whether the type of a particular textbox is date or text in Javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements()
  {
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  alert(x[0].type);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="date" size="25"><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many input elements?">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date and time based input times are [usually not available](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) on desktop browsers. As such, input elements with such a type defined will default to the `text` type.

So when you access the element’s `type` you get whatever type the browser is actually using for that element.

If you want to get the value you actually specified, ignoring whether the browser knows it or not, you can use `getAttribute` to the the original value:

```
alert(x[0].getAttribute('type')); // date
```

Answer (score 1):

Your browser should support `input type="data"`, otherwise browser will recognize type as `text`.

Support Table here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 1):

`type` is a calculated property of the [`input` DOM node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). As such, it reflects what the browser thinks it should be. The value can only be from the list of supported values for the browser at hand, defaulting to `text`, if unknown. Example:

```
<input type="foo">
```

will also yield `element.type === 'text'`. In this case, your browser does not support the `type="date"` method and falls back to a plain text input field. (This is designed behaviour in the HTML5 spec.)